# Application settings fom custom XML file, loading and error-handling

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm working on a legacy application that uses a static class to store settings that are read from a custom XML file.
However, as part of a slight upgrade to the module, the customer would like to see, at runtime, which fields are missing.
Consider the following Settings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
    <configuration>
        <API>
            <log>
                <type>09</type>
                <location>C:\Test\Test.log</filename>
            </log>
        </API>
    </configuration>
</appSettings>
```

The settings are currently read into the static class using an XMLReader (seen below):

```
        using (XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader("Settings.xml"))
        {
            xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("API");
            xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("log");
            xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("type");
            this.logtype = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString(); 
        //snip...
        }
```

This same code is used to read each and every setting.  There has to be a better way.  Is there any way that I can read the XML values into each corresponding property, and generate an error if it's null?
I'm attempting to design the static Settings class as such:

```
public static class Settings
    {
        private static string logtype

        public static string LogType
        {
            get
            { return logtype; }

            set
            { logtype = value; }
        }
    }
```

And then use something like the following to "grab" the values:

```
public static void initSettings()
        {
            appSettings.LogType = read the configuration\API\log\type field from xml;
        }
```

I'm pretty sure that I'd just check for the null character in the property constructor, but how would I do the 'read the configuration\API\log\type field from xml' part of the initSettings method?

Comment: Any reason you are not just using standard XML Serialization on a Settings class marked as Serializable?  You may have to some additional error-checking for null properties, but that's somewhat trivial as well.

Comment: @WonkotheSane Unfortunately my knowledge of XML Serialization is limited.  Do you have a link to a good tutorial?

Comment: Just Google for "XML Serialization C#".  If I get a chance late tonight to put an example here, I will, but there are lots of examples online.

Comment: does the xml log would contain only 1 log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use XMLDocument / XPath. Something like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("Settings.xml");
appSettings.LogType = doc.SelectSingleNode("/appSettings/configuration/API/log/type").InnerText;
```

Actually I would prefer to use Serialization. Maybe the standard serialization a [YAXLib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34045/Yet-Another-XML-Serialization-Library-for-the-NET#deser), which provides some useful error handling.

Edit: For me it's working with InnerText.

Comment: I tried using the XMLDocument method, and I'm unable to return the string in the XML element.  Does the code above work in your environment?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a development environment right now... Maybe you could try use [.InnerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.innertext.aspx) instead of .Value. But if the example above is complete, it should have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ2XML..Its **COOL**

```
XELement doc=XElement.Load("yourXML.xml");

var LogList=doc.Descendants("configuration").Descendants("API").Descendants("log")
.Select(x=>
new
{
type=x.Element("type").Value;
location=x.Element("location").Value;
}
);
```

Now you can use for-each loop to access each and every log in logList

```
foreach(var log in logList)
{
Console.WriteLine(log.type);
Console.WriteLine(log.location);
}
```

Also you can check if its empty

```
if(log.type==""){//its empty}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use XmlNodeList personally.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("Settings.xml");
// Get element from xml.
XmlNodeList type = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("type");
// The following line assumes that there is only 1 type entry
appSettings.LogType = type[0].InnerText;
```

If there are multiple entries you want to get, just slap in a for statement.

```
for (int i = 0; i < type.Count; i++)
{
    // Do stuff
    appSettings.LogType = type[i].InnerText;
}
```